# I want to pass some values to SP when user select all in report in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services

```
=IIF(Parameters!StatusList.Count=6,Parameters!StatusList.Value="On-Hold, Inactive, Re-opened, Enquiry, Open",Parameters!StatusList.Value)
```

1 - Is there any way to show "select all" except number of rows?

2 - If a user selects "ALL" I want to pass all items except one of them.

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable to me.